# Video sharing app

Tags: android, firebase-storage, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I am building a video chat app using Google Firebase. So far I got it working in so far as, when a user sends a video it gets stored in Firebase Storage and the recipient then is able to play it using ExoPlayer on the Android. But I know this is not what I want to be doing.

1. What I want is when a user sends a video I want to convert that into HLS/DASH and store the manifest in Firebase and then want to do adaptive streaming.
2. What are my options to do that? It appears, at least by my research, that there are NO Android API or any libraries available to do that. What other app developers do when it comes to dealing with user generated video content?
3. Are there any services where I can upload video and then get back a manifest link and store that manifest link in my database?

Comment: `there are NO Android API or any libraries` probably right, but you still can implement your library to do that. `What other app developers do` probably implement it on their server side.`Are there any services` probably, but you know that you should not ask for a library or 3rd-party API here, right?

Comment: I guess what I needed is https://youtu.be/z_EgU_IpNkE

Comment: If the videos are short then you probably can live without the adaptive bit rate - they won't take too long to stream and the solution will be much simpler (you already seem to have it working).